# It wasn't ... that had been somebody's

Tags: grammar

> It wasn’t the slump-shouldered, tentative shuffle that had been
>   Hedra’s when she’d first moved into the apartment.

Why is it Hedra’s but Hedra? And what is the grammar for this word order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Hedra had had a shuffle when she'd first moved in, but this (whatever the author is describing in context) is not that shuffle.

Comment: I see.  "slump-shouldered " modifies noun. I had thought it modifies Hedra.